# How to begin writing an Application Server over Apache?

Tags: apache, cgi, application-server

For my college project, I want to create a simple application server in C that runs over Apache. Like .php, .asp, .jsp, the extension of my files would be .sas.

I have already written a parser which reads the .sas files and generates the output. For example, consider a file index.sas with the below code:

```
<%   
echo "Hello";  
%>
```

Now, if I execute:

> sas index.sas

The result would be:

> Hello

Now I want to use this program as an
application server over Apache just as
PHP, Tomcat, etc. work over Apache. I
have heard of cgi-bin but I think PHP
uses a different approach. I want to
learn the approach which PHP uses.

Please advice.

Comment: why don't you go download the source code to PHP and look at it.  Your question boils down to 'how do I write a scripting language' which is a little broad for SO.

Comment: No. I have already written the language and the parser. I just want to know how to use it over Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little correction: Apache HTTP Server is **not** required to be able to run Apache Tomcat as webserver. Apache Tomcat is at its own already a full fledged webserver. Your confusion is probably caused by the [Tomcat Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) which could be used to connect Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat together to be able to serve PHP/JSP behind one same HTTP port.

As to your actual question, PHP can be installed as CGI module or ASAPI (Apache Server API) module. If you want to program a CGI module for Apache HTTP Server, then you may find [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html#) useful. If you want to write an ASAPI module, then you may find [those documentations](http://modules.apache.org/reference.php) useful.

Comment: Hmm... the 1st para sounds interesting, I did not know that! But why did they create a new web server for Tomcat when they already had HTTP server?

Comment: Why are you creating a new scripting language when there are already so many? ;-)

Humor aside, If I remember correctly, the original Tomcat came from Sun and was taken ovrer by Apache Foundation. Wasn't it called JServer or something like that... I could be mistaken, it's been a while.

Comment: @Cracker: because it serves an entirely different purpose: a 100% pure Java webserver/servletcontainer so that it can run everywhere without the need to create/distribute/download separate platform-specific (windows, linux, unix, solaris, etc) software. Java is namely platform independent.

Comment: @cjstehno: Oh..ok.. I got your humor now! :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a module utilizing the Apache API.

Some basic documentation with examples can be found here.

http://www.auburn.edu/docs/apache/mod/mod_example.html

Answer (score 0):

**No, no, no!!! Did I say "no" enough? :)**

You don't need to create a new module or look at PHP source code. Talking about re-inventing the wheel using a square boulder.

The easiest thing to do is to use mod_cgi. That is, you use CGI to have Apache forward the request to your SAS interpreter.

[Apache 1.3x] - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_cgi.html

[Apache 2.0x] - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cgi.html

[CGI] - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Now, if you do not want to use CGI (don't know why unless it is expressively forbidden by your homework instructions), then yeah, you will have to create a module. For that take a look at this as an starting point (courtesy of google):

http://threebit.net/tutorials/apache2_modules/tut1/tutorial1.html

Good luck with that, though. It could become labor-intensive.

Hope it helps.